# Scheme - SubSets of a list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I need to write a function that will produce all of the subsets of a given list. I have a recursive version that uses map but for a bonus I am asked to create a function that does it without using explicit recursion, a local, or any abstract list functions. I am allowed to use `cons`, `empty?`, `empty`, `first`, `rest` and `cond`. I am on the verge of a meltdown - any suggestions? Should I be using a lambda statement for each recursion in need to perform?

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt that your professor is asking you to create or use the Y-Combinator in order to solve this problem, but if you want to try doing it that way, here's some code that might help.  In laymans terms, the y-combinator is a way of making a function without having to define anything, using the power of the lambda calculus.  If you have a working definition(which you mentioned that you do), then converting it to lambdas isn't too difficult.  I'll go through the steps and try my hardest to explain it below, but it is a very difficult concept, and one of the most "mind-blowing" ideas in functional programming.

The following is a normally defined function that will return the length of a given list:

```
;; mylength : [listof Any] -> Number
;; returns the length of xs
(define (mylength xs)
  (if (empty? xs)
      0
      (+ 1 (mylength (rest xs)))))
```

Now, to begin moving out of the standard realm of definitions and explicit recursion, let's make `mylength` a lambda expression that, given a function that is capable of determining the length of a list, returns the length of a given list, `ys`.

```
;; ys is a [Listof Any]
;; mylength is a function that returns the length of a list
(λ (ys)
  (cond [(empty? ys) 0]
        [else (+ 1 (mylength (rest ys)))]))
```

The problem with this code is that we *don't want* to have `mylength` in our code at all.  To get you thinking the right way, remember that the entire point of this lambda function *is to return the length of a given list*.  That'll seem like a cryptic message for now, but you'll see what I  mean in a few lines.

Anyway, the next step in expressing this definition using only lambdas is to make the length function an argument of the lambda function, like this:

```
;; ys is a [Listof Any]
(λ (len ys)
  ;; if ys is empty, return 0.
  (if (empty? ys) 0
      ;; otherwise, call len again, passing len itself as it's 1st argument.
      (+ 1 (len len (rest ys)))))
```

It's probably confusing seeing this line at the end of the code there:
  `(+ 1 (len len (rest ys)))))`  After all, `len` is a function that just takes a list and returns it's length, right?  **WRONG.**  We don't *have* a function that takes a list and returns it's length - we can't use a function like the first `mylength` function mentioned here.  We need some other function whose purpose is to return the length of a list.  If you recall what I "cryptically" said a few lines up,

> remember that the entire point of this lambda function *is to return the length of a given list*

So, if this lambda function we have returns the length of a given list, and the function we need returns the length of a given list...whoa.  Are you thinking what I'm thinking?

```
((λ (len ys) (if (empty? ys) 0 
                  (+ 1 (len len (rest ys)))))
  (λ (len xs) (if (empty? xs) 0
                  (+ 1 (len len (rest xs))))) '(your list here))
```

"What!?" you're probably thinking - "You can *do* that!?"

The answer, my friend, is yes.  Yes you can.  If you're lost, take a good, hard, careful look at the code above.  Let's call the outer lambda function `func 1`, and the inner lambda function `func 2`.  `func 1` is the same function that we wrote before. That part makes sense, right?  `func 1` takes some other function, `len`, and a list, `ys`, and attempts to return the length of `ys`.  Since the purpose of `len` in `func 1` is the *same purpose* that `func 1` has itself, we can pass what is essentially `func 1` as the `len` argument of the outer lambda.

To understand it a little better, let's pass in the list `'(1)` into our new, weird, lambda-monster:

First step:

`(empty? '(1)) -> FALSE`

the outer lambda determines that `'(1)` isn't empty, so it evaluates the next step.

`(+ 1 (len len (rest '(1))))

`(rest '(1))` evaluates to `empty`:

`(+ 1 (len len empty))`

and len is equal to

`(λ (len xs) (if (empty? xs) 0
                      (+ 1 (len len (rest xs)))))`, so the above expands to:

```
((λ (len ys) (if (empty? ys) 0 
                  (+ 1 (len len (rest ys)))))
  (λ (len xs) (if (empty? xs) 0
                  (+ 1 (len len xs)))) empty)
```

and then `empty` gets pushed through the outer lambda as `ys`, and the first conditional statement is evaluated:

`(empty? ys)`

`(empty? empty) -> TRUE`

So the `(len len empty)` call returns `0`.  It now goes to the next step:

`(+ 1 0)', which evaluates to`1`, which is the length of the list`'(1)`.

This is a very difficult concept to understand, and I don't think I did a very good job of explaining the concept as much as I did help you run through the steps necessary to identify it.  If you come out of this understanding how the Y-Combinator works, I'll be sufficiently impressed - both by your ability to understand my ramblings, and my ability to explain such a confusing concept.

```
 1. (empty? '(1)) -> FALSE
 2. (+ 1 (len len (rest ys)))

((λ (len ys) (if (empty? '(1)) 0 
                  (+ 1 (len len (rest ys)))))
  (λ (len xs) (if (empty? xs) 0
                  (+ 1 (len len (rest xs))))) '(your list here))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, doing that without any recursion sounds like it would be quite difficult. Would you be allowed to use the letrec as described here? http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#(form._((lib._racket/private/letstx-scheme..rkt)._letrec))

That could do it for you if it's allowed, but otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: We haven't coved let or letrec in the course so no, not allowed to use it. It's certainly a challenging problem. My recursive function uses a local to prevent repeated evaluations of a recursive call, it defines a constant which is the recursive call. I use map to cons the first element onto the subsets that I find then cons append the result onto the rest of the list. I can write a my map function that uses folder and lambs but I think I need to write a folder function using only lambda as well and then somehow wrap the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, it sounds like the idea here is to use one of the 'fold' functions, rather than making the recursive calls in your code. If you're familiar enough with 'fold', this is not impossible. Essentially, you need to model your process by thinking first about what information needs to be computed at each step in the process, and then how to combine the new information with the old information.

I think your best bet here is to write this down:

```
(define (all-subsets l) (foldl ..?.. ..?.. l))
```

... and then stare at it until you can think of a good name for the combining/helper function. Keep in mind that the helper function may itself use fold or map. Picking the right name for this helper function is where most of the difficult/creative work is.

Comment: Hi John, foldl is an abstract list function though, is it not? If so, verboten :P

Comment: Is it possible to write the equivalent of foldr with a lambda? If so, how would it recurse on the rest of the list? Lambda doesn't implicitly recurse, does it?

Comment: After doing a fair bit of reading on the issue, I think I need to use Y combinator to accomplish this - but I have no idea how to write something so complex - is there a standard guide or process or any information of writing functions with the y-combinator that I can read about to learn how to reason about all this? I tried and it's quite possibly the most confusing thing ever!

Comment: The Y combinator is a lovely way to model recursion in a language that doesn't support it otherwise, but I'd be surprised if that's what your instructor is asking for. If it is, though, take a look at Matthias Felleisen's "The Why of Y". Here's one link to it: www.ps.uni-saarland.de/courses/sem-prog97/material/YYWorks.ps. There's also a Richard Gabriel piece on the same topic; it's also good. I get them both on the first page of google results, but then, google knows what I like....

Comment: Haha... I've come to the same conclusion after spending a good seven hours last night getting nowhere. I've managed to write a non-recursive, pure lambda version of the factorial function, but I'm now trying to write a simple function that acts as (map sqr numlist) would and squares each number in a list...